# validate that keyboard input only supports words in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

First, I am new and I was looking for if there are more questions like this and I didn't see anything.

I am programming a simple library in which you can write data about the books that you enter. I have divided the program into two files: one for the classes and methods and the other for the use of these.

I have a function for the number of pages of the book that, if you write letters, skip an error. The problem comes when I try that, in other functions (author, editorial ...), only allow letters.

My code:

BIBLIOTECA.py

```
class Libro():

      def __init__(self):
            self.autor = ""
            self.paginasTotales = 0

      def setPaginasTotales(self, paginasTotales):
            try:
                 self.paginasTotales = int(paginasTotales)
            except ValueError:
                 print("\n\n ERROR")
                 self.paginasLeidas = 0

      def getPaginasTotales(self):
            return self.paginasTotales

      def setAutor(self, autor):
            try:
                 self.autor = str(autor)
            except ValueError:
                 print("\n\n ERROR")
                 self.autor = ""

     def getAutor(self):
            return self.autor
libro = Libro()
```

USE_BIBLIOTECA.py

```
 elif (opcion == 3):

    while True:
        print("""\n\n\n OPCIONES A MODIFICAR EN LIBRO \n
        1 - Autor/es
        2 - Editorial
        3 - Idioma
        4 - Nº de páginas leidas
        5 - Nº de páginas
        6 - Regresar al menu anterior
        """)
        opcion3 = int(input("Seleccione una opción: "))
        print("Libro: " + str(tituloLibro))

        if (opcion3 == 1):
            autor = input("Autor/es: ")
            libro.setAutor(autor)
   *
   *
   *
 elif (opcion == 5):
    print(" \n\n DATOS DEL LIBRO \n ")
    print("Autor/es: " + str(libro.getAutor()))
```

I would like that, if the user wrote a number in author, that he printed the error and it was empty in "DATOS DEL LIBRO" but I do not get it.

Comment: can you post the whole file?

Comment: Sorry @Nsikan I didn't remember to write the code! My code is below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function gives a string, so doing str() over its result does nothing.

You could do the inverse of what you do for the number of pages. If the int() fails, it's correct; if it succeeds, it's an error:

```
def setAutor(self, autor):
    try:
        self.autor = int(autor)
        print("\n\n ERROR")
        self.autor = ""
    except ValueError:
        self.autor = autor
        pass
```

You could also use regular expressions if you want to give more restrictions to the input.

```
import re
AUTHOR_REGEX = "[^\d]+"  
def setAutor(self, autor):
    if re.fullmatch(AUTHOR_REGEX, autor):
        self.autor = autor
    else:
        print("\n\n ERROR")
        self.autor = ""
```

The regex I gave is the simplest you could do that follows your restriction of not being a number, but you could create a more complex one with spaces and special characters restrictions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a question about the regex. I would like to make a rule that when writing a first and last name, separated by a space, this would not admit numbers. Thank you for your speed in answering

Comment: @AlanT [^\d\s]+( [^\d\s]+)* Here a regex that does not accept numbers. It accepts multiple names like "Gabriel García Márquez". You can test your regexes here https://regex101.com/

Comment: I am running my program in the console and with that regex, it accepts numbers in the second place. For example: Juan 23311. My code is up. Thanks for helping me

Comment: @AlanT oh excuse me you should use the function re.fullmatch() instead of re.match(). Edited the response.

Comment: Do you know some web in that explain how to use the regex? I would like to learn it. I would like to put a condition, which admits letters, space and number but, if someone writes only numbers, leave error. I'm trying to do it but I do not know what I'm doing.